# Create trigger onChange in React Component

Tags: reactjs, events, components, onchange

I have a component in react and I want to create an event "onChange" who can be detect by react by an other component.

```js
const MyFirstComponent = () => {
  //doSomething
  //How can I create event here who can be detect by the onChange in the MySecondComponent
  return (
    <p>
      Something
    </p>
  )
}

const MySecondComponent = () => {
  const handleOnChange = (event) => {//I want this can be launch by MyFirstComponent
    //doSomething
  }
  return (
      <MyFirstComponent onChange={handleOnChange}>
  )
}
```

Maybe there are better ways to get information out ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the HandleOnChange as props as you did it's a good idea . And then you can get it in your first composant like this :

```js
const MyFirstComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <p onChange={props.OnChange}></p>
  )
}
```

Comment: My goal being to do the opposite, to switch from MyFirstComponent to MySecondComponent, maybe there is another way than the onChange ?